# How to install libpq-dev (14.0-1) on ubuntu 21.10?

Tags: dpkg, postgresql, 21.10

I already have the postgresql of latest version(14.0-1.pgdg21.04+1).

I want to setup dev environment for psycopg2(https://github.com/psycopg/psycopg2/) library locally and it requires `libpq-dev` for that.

Running `sudo apt-get install libpq-dev` gives following error

> The following packages have unmet dependencies:
> libpq-dev : Depends: libpq5 (= 13.4-1) but 14.0-1.pgdg21.04+1 is to be installed
> E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.

It's because ubuntu repository(https://packages.ubuntu.com/impish/libpq-dev) doesn't have the latest version yet.

But I've found that debian sid repository have the latest version
[libpq-dev (14.0-1)](https://packages.debian.org/sid/libpq-dev)

I can download the .deb file and dpkg install it but the downside is I can't upgrade it.
Also, I don't want to add debian in my sources list, because it might mess a lot of other things.

So, what's the easiest way to download this package?

Answer (score 2):

For me running the following code solved the problem

```
sudo apt-get install libpq-dev
```

Answer (score 0):

Just install the required version of `libpq5` and reinstall `libpq-dev`:

```
sudo apt-get install libpq5=13.4-1
sudo apt-get install libpq-dev
```

I suppose for `psycopg2` you also need:

```
sudo apt-get install python3-dev
```

Comment: Thanks for you answer. Welcome to Ask Ubuntu. I had made it clear in the title and description as well that I need to install the latest version(14.0-1). Downgrading is obviously a solution but in my case not helpful.